# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to collect each people's grade in the special subject of course with python. I get each person's grade one by one. For this reason, I write a SQL code like below. row come from easrlier sql result and it prints subject and course and it shows like

> ('CS', '201')

categoriesWithFeedback contains unique nickname. I write sql code but it cannot understand row contains 2 parameter I think.

```
sqlgrade = "SELECT `grade` FROM `enrolledtable` WHERE `subject`=%s and `course`=%s and `nickname`=%s"

IE_students.append(categoriesWithFeedback)

cursor.execute(sqlgrade, (row, categoriesWithFeedback))

IEaveragegrades += cursor.fetchone()
```

`

Python ERROR is that

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\wamp\www\MLWebsite\website\new.py", line 85, in 
>       cursor.execute(sqlgrade, (row, categoriesWithFeedback))   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 163, in
>   execute
>       query = self.mogrify(query, args)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 142, in
>   mogrify
>       query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Can anyone help me to solve that error? I don't want to use sqlparse if there is any solution without that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has 3 placeholders and the way you are passing the arguments, it receives 2, because the `row` param is still a tuple.
The second argument `(row, categoriesWithFeedback)` is actually `(("CS", "201"), "someOtherValue")` instead of `("CS", "201", "someOtherValue")`.

You need to unpack the row tupple

**Edit after comment:** 
You can unpack the tuple in 2 ways:

Python 3: `(*row, categoriesWithFeedback)` which will yield the wanted result.

Python 2: `foo, bar = row`. This will assign "CS" to foo param and 201 to bar param. The pass it in the query like `(foo, bar, categoriesWithFeedback)`

Comment: How can I unpack the row. I try to write like that `cursor.execute(sqlgrade, (row, (categoriesWithFeedback)))` but it is not working.

Comment: If you are on python3 the '*' in front of your tuple unpacks it, eg:
a = (1,2) then *a will unpack the tuple so in the case of an example like (a,7) adding an astrisk in front of a will do the job for you (*a,7) -> (1,2,7)

If you are on python2 you have to perform a thing like a,b = row and "CS" will go to a param and 201 to b param and then pass it to the query

Answer (score 0):

I solve like that

```
cursor.execute(sqlgrade, (row[0], row[1], categoriesWithFeedback))
```